# Netbeans: how to make gui events method as protected instead of private

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, protected, gui-builder

From the Gui builder in NetBeans 7.4 I can make action methods such as

```
private void btnFilterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }
```

Is there any way to let NetBeans create protected mathods instead of private ones ?

```
protected void btnFilterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd want your code to do this.

Comment: If you dig around the preferences you should be able to adjust this, but is agree with HovercraftFullOfEels, why would you want this? If you want to re-use the code, place that code in a suitable method that the event handler can call

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:I have sub-classed this class and I want to trigger a different action on that button-click. Another solution would be to keep the generated method private and let it call a new intermediary method that I will override in the subclass, but I found this less readable.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : I already dug far... :/

Comment: Hmmm, seems I must have been thinking about the variable modifiers.  I would, instead, create `protected` methods that you can call from your event handlers instead...

Comment: @MadProgrammer : that's what I've done in the meantime.